# Remove the @ from azure postgresql username

Tags: azure, azure-postgresql

When creating a new postgresql instance on the azure portal or even the CLI, the username is automatically made to be like user@databasename so i can't use it on a database string, funny enough Azure has an entire section with connection strings, for example the **node.js** example is

```
postgres://{your_username}:{your_password}@{host_name}:5432/{your_database}?ssl=true
```

So if we substitute the values we would end up with something like this

```
postgres://user@databasename:password@host.azure.com:5432/database_name?ssl=true
```

Can you see the problem? two `@`, this is completely wrong, `node.js` can't parse this, I have the same problem on `ruby`, this is not a valid url.

How can I change the username to remove the @part ?

Answer (score 2):

use %40 for the second @. It should work.

Comment: You are the savior!